# Handling NullPointerException gracefully with web.xml on JBoss AS7

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, web.xml

I try to handle all exceptions with the following snippet in the web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

However, when a `NullPointerException` occurs it still shows the default JBoss error page with the stack trace. How can I handle the NullpointerException gracefully?

Comment: Did you try java.lang.Throwable as well?

Comment: @Efthymis why would that help?

Comment: I am not suggesting it would help. I was just asking so as to have a better understanding about the things you 've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Extend `ExceptionHandlerFactory` and `ExceptionHandlerWrapper` in two separate classes.

**(MyExceptionHandlerFactory and MyExceptionHandlerWrapper)**

Register your custom subclass like this.

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        com.sample.exceptions.MyExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

now you can handle every exception in handle method of your MyExceptionHandlerWrapper class.

Here is a tutorial from the JSF Lead himself.

[Dealing Gracefully ViewExpiredException JSF2](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2)

Comment: thanks will try this. but is this a bug in jsf? or what is the reason behind this behaviour?